# how to display values of an arraylist defined in servlet using ajax call

Tags: java, ajax

Can anyone please help me with below code

servlet:

below servlet is for statically defining an array.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class SampleAjax extends HttpServlet{  

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
        {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        string plociyno = "abd1234";
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        if (policyno.equals("abc1234"))
        {
        List dataList= new ArrayList(); 
        dataList.add("automated refund possible");
        request.setAttribute("data",dataList);            

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("refund.jsp");  
        if (dispatcher != null){  
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        }

        }
```

and my JSP: 
JSP for displaying the values of the arraylist in a table. I want to do the same thing but using Ajax. Please help.

```
<html
    <body><table id= "table" border="0" width="303">
    <tr>

    <td width="250"><b>Your Policy Refund Details is:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <%Iterator itr; %> 

    <% ArrayList refund= (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("data");

    if(refund != null){ 

        for(itr=refund.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){ 
        %>
        <tr>

        <td><%=itr.next()%></td> 

        </tr>
        <%}}%>        

    </table>        

    </body>
    </html>
```

how can I display this arraylist values using ajax? Please help.

Comment: There is a lot of information out there about this kind of subject. A quick Google resulted in: http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/jobs_employees_jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

well,

first create a function ie. an url which will display your arraylist value.

inside your doGet()

```
if(request.getParameter("get").equals("array")){
//code to display array elements
}
```

here the ajax is made to call your servlet with servlet?get=array

```
$.ajax({
url: servlet?get=array,
data: data, //if you need any
success: success,
dataType: dataType // The type of data expected from the server xml? json?text?html?pdf? 
});
```

Now you can display the text from AJAX code.
If you only want jsp inside ajax,
it's quite simple, call the entire page in your ajax code.

```
$.get(
"http://some-remote-site",
function(data) { alert(data); },
);
```

I don't see what problem you got here. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by simply adding

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

And then

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${data}" varStatus="i">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row[0]}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${row[1]}" /></td>
...
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

By this way you can display the ArrayList data easily.